# Build a coupled map lattice using 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, iteration

So I'm trying to build a coupled map lattice on my computer.

A coupled map lattice (CML) is given by this eq'n:

[image: The equation]

where, the function f(Xn) is a logistic map :

[image: The function]

with x value from 0-1, and r=4 for this CML.

**Note:** 'n' can be thought of as time, and 'i' as space

I have spent a lot of time understanding the iterations and i came up with a code as below, however i'm not sure if this is the correct code to iterate this equation.

**Note:** I have used 2d numpy arrays, where rows are 'n' and columns are 'i' as obvious from the code.

**So basically, I want to develop a code to simulate this equation, and here is my take on that**

**Don't jump to the code directly, you won't understand what's happening without bothering to look at the equations first.**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

'''The 4 definitions created below are actually similar and only vary in their indexings. These 4 
   have been created only because of the if conditions I have put in the for loop '''
def logInit(r,x):
    y[n,0]=r*x[n,0]*(1-x[n,0])
    return y[n,0]

def logPresent(r,x):
    y[n,i]=r*x[n,i]*(1-x[n,i])
    return y[n,i] 

def logLast(r,x):
    y[n,L-1]=r*x[n,L-1]*(1-x[n,L-1])
    return y[n,L-1] 

def logNext(r,x):
    y[n,i+1]=r*x[n,i+1]*(1-x[n,i+1])
    return y[n,i+1]

def logPrev(r,x):
    y[n,i-1]=r*x[n,i-1]*(1-x[n,i-1])
    return y[n,i-1]

# 2d array with 4 row, 3 col. I created this because I want to store the evaluated values of log 
  function into this y[n,i] array

y=np.ones(12).reshape(4,3)

# creating an array of random numbers between 0-1 with 4 rows 3 columns  

np.random.seed(0)
x=np.random.random((4,3))

L=3
r=4
eps=0.5

for n in range(3):
    for i in range(L):


        if i==0:
            x[n+1,i]=(1-eps)*logPresent(r,x) + 0.5*eps*(logLast(r,x)+logNext(r,x))

        elif i==L-1:
              x[n+1,i]=(1-eps)*logPresent(r,x) + 0.5*eps*(logPrev(r,x) + logInit(r,x))

        elif i > 0 and i < L - 1:
             x[n+1,i]=(1-eps)*logPresent(r,x) + 0.5*eps*(logPrev(r,x) +logNext(r,x))

        print(x)
```

This does give an output. Here it is:

```
[[0.5488135  0.71518937 0.60276338]
 [0.94538775 0.82547604 0.64589411]
 [0.43758721 0.891773   0.96366276]
 [0.38344152 0.79172504 0.52889492]]

[[0.5488135  0.71518937 0.60276338]
 [0.94538775 0.82547604 0.92306303]
 [0.2449672  0.49731638 0.96366276]
 [0.38344152 0.79172504 0.52889492]]

[[0.5488135  0.71518937 0.60276338]
 [0.94538775 0.82547604 0.92306303]
 [0.2449672  0.49731638 0.29789622]
 [0.75613708 0.93368134 0.52889492]]
```

But I'm very sure this is not what I'm looking for.

If you can please figure out a correct way to iterate and loop the CML equation with code ? Suggest me the changes I have to make. Thank you very much!!

**You'll have to think about the iterations and looping to be made to simulate this equation. It might be tedious, but that's the only way you can suggest me some changes in my code.**

Comment: Do you know of a way to validate your results? Btw I get different results than the 3 arrays you provided. 12 in total

Comment: If you use `x=np.zeros((N+1, L));
x[0, :] = np.random.random(L)`, it becomes clearer what element of your grid is updated. You only have tot initialise the grid for the first time step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations seem fine to me. You could improve the speed by using vectorization along the space dimension and by reusing your intermediate results `y`. I restructured your program a little, but in essence it does the same thing as before. For me the results look plausible. The image shows the random initial vector in the first row and as the time goes on (top to bottom) the coupling comes in to play and little islands and patterns form.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

L = 128  # grid size
N = 128  # time steps 
r = 4
eps = 0.5

# Create random values for the initial time step
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.zeros((N+1, L))
x[0, :] = np.random.random(L)

# Create a helper matrix to save and reuse part of the calculations
y = np.zeros((N, L))

# Indices for previous, present, next position for every point on the grid
idx_present = np.arange(L)        #   0, 1, ..., L-2, L-1
idx_next = (idx_present + 1) % L  #   1, 2, ..., L-1, 0
idx_prev = (idx_present - 1) % L  # L-1, 0, ..., L-3, L-2

def log_vector(rr, xx):
    return rr * xx * (1 - xx)

# Loop over the time steps
for n in range(N):
    # Compute y once for the whole time step and reuse it 
    # to build the next time step with coupling the neighbours
    y[n, :] = log_vector(rr=r, xx=x[n, :])
    x[n+1, :] = (1-eps)*y[n,idx_present] + 0.5*eps*(y[n,idx_prev]+y[n,idx_next])

# Plot the results
plt.imshow(x)
```

[image: resulting grid with N=L=128, r=4, eps=0.5]

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this. This is what I was exactly looking for, from past couple of weeks. I couldn't think about indexing the CML before, the way you have done here(idx_present, next, prev) . Also while plotting I thought for days, about plotting every element of the array with a point and stuff. Couldn't think of this way of plotting it even after referring to many documentations. Your answer is perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @sceleronomic I have a lot of simulations like this to be performed and I want an advice on what to learn in order to compute scientific stuff  and how to surf  those things in documentations(they are lengthy too). I am familiar with the basics of programming  through C, so I know the introductory concepts.   Developing a coder logic on a given scientific data, (just like you could manage to think about idx_present, next prev etc)  is the first thing I'm worried on, and plotting it is the 2nd thing I worry.

Comment: @DharilShah I am happy that I could help you. There are a lot of courses and material on the web for you to become a better programmer (Textbooks, edX, HackerRank, Udemy, Brilliant, YouTube, Documentations and Cookbooks for `numpy`, `matplotlib`, ...). But I guess the best way is just to keep practicing. If you have a topic you are interested in and have some ideas how to analyse it via code you are ready to go. And if you get stuck along the way StackOverflow is there to yelp you out ;)